# Unable to a build an apex query string

Tags: apex

I have a string where object names are enclosed in <>. Something like this->

```
         String source = 'I have <name> and <id>';
```

Object name is stored in another String ->

```
          String objectName = 'Contact';
```

I need to get the fields like this->

```
          String fields = 'name,id';
```

How to achieve this?

So that I can use it in query ->

```
           String query = 'Select '+fields+' from '+objectName;
           List<sObject> myList= Database.Query(query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways of doing this, but how about something like:

```
String source = 'I have <name> and <id>';     
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(?m)<.*?>').matcher(source);
while (m.find()) 
{
    System.debug( source.substring(m.start()+1, m.end()-1 ) );
}
```

Comment: yeah it worked :)

Comment: But its not working when I am using like this:                 String source = 'I have {account.name} and {id}';     
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(?m){.*?}').matcher(source);
while (m.find()) 
{
    System.debug('Result::'+source.substring(m.start()+1, m.end()-1 ) );
}

Comment: Yeah, think you'll need a couple of slashes in there for that, try '(?m)\\{.*?\\}' as your pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to realize the list of fields:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('<([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)>').matcher(source);
Set<String> fields = new Set<String>();
for(Integer groupNum = 1; groupNum < m.groupCount(); groupNum++) {
    fields.add(m.group(groupNum));
}
fields.retainAll(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySEt());
String queryFields = String.join(new List<String>(fields), ',');
```

Comment: Did you try this code @sfdcfox? I can't seem to get it to work..